# Qt5Widgets cmake error

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

While building a catkin workspace I need to perform the following steps:

```
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
$ cd ~/overlay_ws/
$ catkin_make
```

as mentioned on [catkin tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) step 2.3
Following the last step induced an error:

```
 By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

So to fix that I installed Qt5 from [the website](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu). Now I had to manually change the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` using `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$ENV{HOME}\qt5\5.5\gcc_64"` to include qt5.

And then I tried again which gave me another error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:271 (message):
  Could not find 'share/std_msgs/cmake/std_msgs-msg-paths.cmake' (searched in
  '/home/pb/ROS01/overlay_ws/devel').
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ros_tutorials/roscpp_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:11 (generate_messages)
```

to solve the above error, a forum recommended me to do the source command again

```
 $ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

Performing the source command again removes the path variable again. Now I am stuck in a loop.

**Operating System Details**
As mentioned in comments, it might be useful for the community to answer based on the operating system I am using as well as the particular installation process I adopted to install ROS.
Current OS - Ubuntu 14.04
ROS - indigo
Installation guide followed to install indigo - http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

**Can someone tell me how to change environment path variable properly? Example - how to change CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in this case?**

Kindly help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252079/qt5widgets-cmake-error/) by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-01-17**:
Checking the [Qt Cmake Manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) suggests to:

> In order for find_package to be successful, ... the Qt5_DIR must be set in the CMake cache to the location of the Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake file.

Have you tried this? I have no setup, so I cannot...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:\

> While building a catkin workspace

Could you please tell us what package(s) you are trying to build? The last time I've had to manually install Qt on an Ubuntu system has been very long ago, so only in specific circumstances should that be necessary.

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-17**:
@gvdhoorn - I am trying to build https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git which is basically the ros_tutorials package. I am following the steps from the website: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying
and the step 2.2 instructs me to clone from git and build it in step 2.3

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
Qt5 is correctly listed as a dependency of `turtlesim` (the pkg that needs it in `ros_tutorials`). Can you please tell us what OS you are trying this on, how you installed ROS, which version it is, etc?

The tutorial doesn't explicitly mention it, but without the necessary prereqs, it won't work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
However, the `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials` in step 1.1 (Preparing the environment) should already have installed all the necessary dependencies, hence my questions about your specific setup.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
Note that the tutorial does it this way as it is a tutorial on *workspace overlaying*, not on general Catkin workspace usage or creation. When overlaying, either all dependencies have already been satisfied, or you are responsible for making sure they are installed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
Another thing:

> `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$ENV{HOME}\qt5\5.5\gcc_64"`

the path separator on Linux/Unix/MacOS(X) is the forward slash (`/`), not a backslash (`\`). The backslash is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), so your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` does not work this way.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
Just realised (but can't test it right now) that it might be that `apt-get` only installed the *runtime* requirements. If, after installing `ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials` (and without the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` tweak) you still get errors, can you run a ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
.. `rosdep check --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src` and add the output to your OP? That should show whether something is missing.

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-22**:
thanks! that worked. Sorry for a late reply.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
What exactly worked? The `rosdep` invocation, or installing `ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials`?

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-23**:
the cmake_prefix_path!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
I would really recommend following 'normal' development practices and just use distribution/system/platform provided libraries (such as qt5) instead. If you ever try to link (by accident) against two different versions of Qt, you'll run into all sorts of (sometimes hard to diagnose) trouble.

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-23**:
Sure, I will take care about that. But the Ubuntu repo. provide qt4 not qt5 while the error wanted me to use qt5.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
Did you make sure to checkout the `indigo-devel` branch of `ros/ros_tutorials`? Or are you trying to build the `kinetic-devel` branch on Indigo? Kinetic uses Qt5, Indigo uses Qt4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably trying to build the Kinetic version of `ros_tutorials` on your Indigo installation. Kinetic uses Qt5, Indigo uses Qt4.

Check that you have `indigo-devel` as the current branch in `/home/pb/ROS01/overlay_ws/src/ros_tutorials`, and not `kinetic-devel`. If the wrong branch is checked out, change to `indigo-devel`, delete the `build` and `devel` folders in `/home/pb/ROS01/overlay_ws`, **undo** the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` changes that you made (ideally remove the Qt version you installed using the installer from the website) and try building again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-23**:
Do you have any experience with KinectV2 SLAM with gmapping. I am stuck at pointcloud_to_laserscanner part. Do I need to install any other driver (apart from libfreenect2).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
That is a completely unrelated issue, and I would suggest you open a new question to keep things on-topic.

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-24**:
Hey! How can I check if I have the right branch or not. In my case it doesn't mention any branch. It has 4 folder there - roscpp_tutorials, rospy_tutorials,  ros_tutorials & turtlesim

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-24**:
`cd` to your local clone, then run `git status`. It should tell you what branch you're on. If you want a list of all branches, you could use `git branch -av`.

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-24**:
What worked for me! - using `git clone --version indigo-devel git://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git` rather than using the `wstool` command mentioned on the same page. How can I use the --version option with wstool however?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-24**:
These are all new questions, only tangentially related to your original issue. Please open a new question for them.

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-24**:
Here we go with a new question: http://answers.ros.org/question/252882/how-to-clone-with-proper-branch-options-using-wstool/